# in SQL, how do you retrieve set that contains all the values of another set?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a standard spj database, I'm trying to retrieve only the suppliers who supply every color available to parts. So if p1 = green, p2 = blue, and p3 = green. Then any supplier who supplies p1 or p2 will work. Or anyone who supplies p2 and p3 will fulfill.

I was thinking of a set division with 'not exists'

```
SELECT DISTINCT snum,
                sname
FROM   supplier
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT pnum
                   FROM   part
                   WHERE  pnum IN (SELECT color
                                   FROM   part)
                          AND pnum NOT IN (SELECT pnum
                                           FROM   spj
                                           WHERE  spj.snum = supplier.snum))
```

Expected output should look:

```
 snum | sname |

 s1   | Smith |
 s5   | Adams |
```

Comment: what o/p you are getting?

Comment: i'm getting 2 columns: supplier number and supplier name, but with much more entries than what is correct. I don't think I am selecting out all the distinct colors available

Comment: Add sample data and expected output which makes yours question more clear.

Comment: Can you please show me the structure for the table that you are using?

Comment: part(pnum, pname, color, weight, city), spj(snum, pnum, jnum, qty). Want to find snum and sname of suppliers who supply at least one part of every possible color

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with a join to a subquery that produces total colors for each part and ensures that the supplier supplies all colors:

```
select snum, sname from
(select snum, sname, spj.pnum, count(distinct color) count
    from supplier
    join spj on spj.snum = supplier.snum
    join part on part.pnum = spj.pnum
    group by snum, sname, spj.pnum) x    
join (select pnum, count(distinct color) count from part) p
    on p.pnum = x.pnum
    and x.count = p.count
```

Comment: There were no outputs. Is there a way without using group by or count?

Comment: @user2934483 Main point is your question is not clear. Please very specific in your question & everything is possible in programming.

Comment: Could you please provide schema and some sample data via an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)?